# Modify SharePoint Online Site Collection URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, url

I have a SharePoint Online private site collection which have called `https//myco.sharepoint.com/sites/coolthing_poc`. Is there a way for me to rename it to `https//myco.sharepoint.com/sites/coolthing` without having to perform a migration?

Comment: OK this is a common question, especially from those who are migrating from SharePoint on-premise. So, please provide a link to someone who has carefully documented how to Migrate a SharePoint online(i.e. Duplicate an existing site) site to a new SharePoint Online site.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, no, not possible a without migration of some sort.

Comment: This is a constant thing I run into, that and renaming the entire tenant.  Too bad I can't get all those business users asking for it to vote on UserVoice.

Comment: And to be fair, it still requires some sort of backup/restore/migration for on premises. Totally agree with the tenant rename. I feel we chose poorly at the start, and have a super long tenant address as a result.

Comment: Thanks for the affirmation. Is there any way to perform a backup/restore/migration in SharePoint Online natively using PowerShell or otherwise?

Comment: There are powershell commandlets to help utilize the Azure Pipeline for migration, but honestly I'd look at third party tools from ShareGate, Metalogix, or Avepoint.